# My machine learning model keeps predicting the wrong thing even though it has a high accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

The model does not predict the right thing even after having a high training accuracy , the reason for that is really an issue, it does not predict well it is suppose to classify malaria images into infected and non infected but it seems not to do that, this model was developed using the cnn transfer learning

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten,Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,load_img
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

# re-size all the images to this
IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224 , 3]

# Import the Vgg 16 library as shown below and add preprocessing layer to the front of VGG
# Here we will be using imagenet weights

mobilnet = VGG19(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE , weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# don't train existing weights
for layer in mobilnet.layers:
layer.trainable = False

# useful for getting number of output classes
# folders = glob('Dataset/Train/*')
enter code here

folders = glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/Train/*')

folders

# our layers - you can add more if you want
x = Flatten()(mobilnet.output)

prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')(x)

# create a model object
model = Model(inputs=mobilnet.input, outputs=prediction)

# view the structure of the model
model.summary()

from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D

# tell the model what cost and optimization method to use
model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Use the Image Data Generator to import the images from the dataset
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

# # Make sure you provide the same target size as initialied for the image size
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory='/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/Train',
                                             target_size = (224, 224),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')

training_set

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/Test',
                                        target_size = (224, 224),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

# simple early stopping
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1)

# fit the model    
# Run the cell. It will take some time to execute
r = model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs= 20,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set),
  # callbacks=[es]
)



# plot the loss
plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label='train loss')
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label='val loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('LossVal_loss')

# plot the accuracy
plt.plot(r.history['accuracy'], label='train acc')
plt.plot(r.history['val_accuracy'], label='val acc')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('AccVal_acc')

# save it as a h5 file


from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model.save('model_vgg19.h5')



y_pred = model.predict(test_set)

y_pred

import numpy as np
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

y_pred

print(y_pred.shape)



from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

model=load_model('model_vgg19.h5')



img=image.load_img('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/Train/Parasite/C111.png',target_size=(224,224))

x=image.img_to_array(img)
x

x.shape

x=x/255

x=np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)

image_data = preprocess_input(x)

print(image_data.shape)

model.predict(image_data)

a=np.argmax(model.predict(image_data), axis=1)

print(a)

if(a==1):
    print("Not infected")
else:
    print("Infected")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, instead of dumping the whole code I kindly suggest you to only add relevant parts i.e plots for loss & accuracy etc.

Comment: Have you checked other prediction metrics besides accuracy? Precision, recall, f1 score? Accuracy is notorious for being a poor training metric on imbalanced classification problems, which medical use-cases often are. Regardless, this _may_ be a better fit for [datascience.se] if you expand to include more detail about your training data

Answer (score 1):

Be advised that `modelfit_generator` is being depreciated. `model.fit` can now handle generators. Steps per epoch really should be `len(training_set)/batch_size` and same for validation steps. In the `test_set` `flow_from_directory` set `shuffle=False`.

Do you know the balance values for your data set? That is the ratio in the training set between samples infected samples/ not infected samples. If this is <.5 your model will tend to predict not infected. For example, if you have 100 samples of infected and 1000 samples of not infected your model will be 90% accurate just by always predicting non-infected. I suggest you modify your early stopping callback as below

```
es=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(  monitor="val_loss",  min_delta=0,
                                    patience=4,  verbose=1,    mode="auto",
                                    baseline=None,  restore_best_weights=True)
```

Increase your number of epochs to say 50 so early stopping gets activated. With restore_best_weights=True it will load the model with the weights for the epoch with the lowest validation loss. I also suggest you use an adjustable learning rate using Keras callback `ReduceLROnPlateau`. This will automatically reduce the learning rate by parameter factor if the validation loss fails to improve for patience number of epochs. My suggested code is given below:

```
tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1,
                                    verbose=1,  mode="auto",  min_delta=0.0001,
                                    cooldown=0,  min_lr=0)
```

set callbacks=[es, rlronp] in model.fit
you are not training the Vgg model which is fine but you might want to fine-tune the model. After you complete training you might do

```
mobilnet.trainable=True
fine_tune_epochs=10
total_epochs=epochs + fine_tune_epochs
r=model.fit(training_set,  validation_data=test_set,  epochs= total_epochs,
           steps_per_epoch=len(training_set)/batch_size,
           validation_steps=len(test_set)/batch_siz,
           callbacks=[es, rlronp], initial_epoch=epoch)
```

To see if your model is really performing well you should create a confusion matrix. get a set of predictions on the test-set as below

```
classes=['infected', 'normal']
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
y_pred=[]
preds=model.predict(train_set, batch_size=batch_size)
for p in preds:
    y_pred.append(np.argmax(p))
y_true=test_set.labels # this is why you set shuffle=False for the train_set
y_true= np.array(labels)        
y_pred=np.array(y_pred)        
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred )
clr = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=classes)
fig_width=8
fig_height=8        
plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height))
 sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, vmin=0, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', cbar=False)       
 plt.xticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation= 90)
 plt.yticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation=0)
 plt.xlabel("Predicted")
 plt.ylabel("Actual")
 plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
 plt.show()    
 print("Classification Report:\n----------------------\n", clr)
```